# str_replace is not removing white spaces

Tags: php, str-replace

i am trying to change any ' ' by a '-'

i am doing like this:

```
 $tagname = $taginfo[1];   /* something like $tagname = 'A tag with spaces' */
 $tagurl = urlencode($tagname);
 $tagsize = 9 + intval($numtags)*2;
 $bla = 'function("'.str_replace(' ','-',$tagname).'")';
```

$bla is going to be used to be attached to the onclick attribute

any idea why the result would be

```
onclick="function('A tag with spaces')"
```

instead of

```
onclick="function('A-tag-with-spaces')"
```

? may the htmlspecialchars have to do something with it?

Comment: Can you copy the original `$taginfo[1]` string here?

Comment: something similar as i posted 'Camión rojo' is a posible one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlencode($tagname);` would turn your white spaces into `%20` so your string would then be

```
A%20tag%20with%20spaces
```

You could either replace `%20` with `-` or do the replace before the encoding.

Comment: so you mean i need to str_replace('%20', '', $str) ??

Comment: That is one option yes, though I think you meant `str_replace('%20', '-', $str);`.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko please note that your answer is wrong, i don't urlenconde $tagname..

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet So, why is it still accepted? And what did you instead?

Comment: After 2 years.. I forgot... I believe I accepted it when the stackoverflow suggestion comes up, salut!